# Можно ли узнать, какие узлы были удалены, какие добавлены, а какие изменены в XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, классы, разметка

Есть некоторый XML, он изменяется в процессе своего существования.

Нужно узнать, какие изменения были проделаны.

Нигде не в XML объектах не пишется эта информация или подобную информацию я могу получить, если буду вести логирование руками, подписавшись на события ?

Вообще появилась у меня некоторая идея:

Что если ввести дополнительный атрибут, например ChangeType, который будет проставляться в узлы над которыми происходили какие-то манипуляции?

Скажем, клиент удалил какой-то узел, но по факту он не удалился, а пометился спец. значением, изменил какой-то узел и появилась соответствующая пометка, добавил узел еще одна пометка.

Потом XML шлется на сервер, изменения регистрируются, атрибут удаляется, а удаленные узлы удаляются.

Comment: Если вы пользуетесь `XElement`, у них есть событие [`Changed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.changed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), можно им воспользоваться тоже. У `XmlElement` кажется своих событий нету. Но в любом случае вы, да, должны подписаться на изменения. `XDocument` не хранит свою историю изменений (зачем она ему нужна?).

Comment: @VladD у XmlDocument есть события, они срабатывают для любого узла принадлежащего документу.

Comment: @rdorn: Точно! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_5

Comment: @VladD и на них как раз можно построить систему логирования, но все равно много ручной работы останется.

Comment: А какая конечная цель такого логирования? просто есть одна мысль, но не факт что она вам подойдет.

Comment: При пересылки такого Xml служба долна сделать корректировки в бд и отослать Xml программе, которая использует его как файл конфигурации.

Comment: читает мысли =) я хотел предложить просто помещать узел в комментарий с меткой времени удаления. Но ваш вариант функциональнее. Да и с помощью LiNQtoXML можно будет выбрать узлы имеющие определенное значение атрибутов.

Comment: можно еще что-то типа разностного XML строить, но это может выйти сильно накладно если изменения близко к корню будут, или в элементах содержащих длинный список вложенных элементов одного уровня

Answer (score 1):

Можешь написать ручками функцию для сравнения после последнего сейва с теперешней версией XML которая лежит в оператике.
Просто сравниваешь все ноды =)

Или же берешь библиотеку для обработки XML вроде того же HTMLAgrilityPack и расширяешь их стандартные методы своим "логированием" изменений. Если там его нет(я не в курсе).